Definition of Colored Noise in terms of White Noise
For context, I was reading Optimal Control and Estimation by Stengel. In a section centered around discussing colored noise, Stengel defines a first-order difference equation $$\tag{1}x_{i+1} = ax_i + \sqrt{1 - a^2} w_i, \qquad a \in [0, 1],$$where $w_i$ is a zero-mean white noise sequence with covariance $\sigma_w^2$. Stengel squares this equation and takes expected values and uses stochastic equilibrium ($\mathbb E[x_{i+1}^2] = \mathbb E[x_i^2]$) to show that $\mathbb E[x_i^2] = \sigma_x^2 = \sigma_w^2$. This is then used to derive the autocovariance of this stochastic sequence.
My main questions are the following:

What is the reason/motivation for the choice of coefficients $a, \sqrt{1 - a^2}$ in $(1)$?
In the next section, Stengel states that for a Markov process, taking $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$, these equations become $$\dot x(t) = fx(t) - fw(t), \qquad \frac{\mathrm d [\sigma_x^2(t)]}{\mathrm d t} = 2f [\sigma_x^2(t) - \sigma_w^2].$$I don't see how the leftmost equation is a natural generalization of $(1)$, and I don't see how the rightmost equation is derived from the left one (or, more generally, why it holds).

Thanks so much!

For 1.) if you instead take $x_{i+1}=ax_i+bw_i$ then computing the variances would instead yield $\mathbb E[x_{i+1}^2]=\sigma_x^2=a^2 \sigma_x^2+b^2 \sigma_w^2$. Hence $b=\sqrt{1-a^2}$ ensures that the two variances are simply equal rather than having $(1-a^2)\sigma_x^2=b^2 \sigma_w^2$.

I see -- so having the variances equal at equilibrium is (an important) part of the definition here?

Thinking further, I wonder if there's a simpler way to formulate this: What is $x_0$? Presumably the initial condition is just $x_0=w_0$, in which case $\mathbb{E}[x_0^2]=\sigma_w^2$ analogous to Stenger's discussion on the previous page. But then stochastic equilibrium directly implies $\sigma_x^2=\sigma_w^2$ and therefore $a^2+b^2=1$ is required.
